# Class does not change on click

Tags: javascript, dom, events, event-handling, dom-events

Button in error box element executes function hide error box but class of error box element is not replaced. The function is also used in submit form when checked if email is valid and the same function executes and works correctly. Event listener is ok because console log from inside the function executes. What could be the problem?

https://codepen.io/Chickenbiscuitoo/pen/ExONgaZ

Error box:

```
<div id="palk_ui_newsletter_error_box"
      class="palk_ui_newsletter_form_group_1_error palk_ui_newsletter_error_hidden">
      <span id="palk_ui_newsletter_error_message"></span>
      <button id="palk_ui_newsletter_error_close">
        <svg width="26" height="26" viewBox="0 0 26 26" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <line x1="7.07031" y1="18.6561" x2="18.384" y2="7.34239" stroke="#9A7C2D" stroke-width="2"
            stroke-linecap="round" />
          <line x1="7.07046" y1="7.34375" x2="18.3842" y2="18.6575" stroke="#9A7C2D" stroke-width="2"
            stroke-linecap="round" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buttons in form which shouldn't submit it, must be **type="button"**

That means you can add type attribute like this:

```
<button id="palk_ui_newsletter_error_close" type="button">
```